# Data repositories like UCI

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, dataset, databases

Are there any other data repositories like UCI and mlData, for biological data?? I want to know about mostly biological data set.

Comment: You might want to consider asking this on OpenData StackExchange http://opendata.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There're lots and tons of data sets for biological data.

- [GenBank Overview](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genbank/)
- [IGSR: The International Genome Sample Resource](http://www.1000genomes.org/)
- [Bioinformation and DDBJ Center](http://www.ddbj.nig.ac.jp/)
- [List of biological databases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_biological_databases)

Answer (score 2):

I do biological network analysis and [here](http://biit.cs.ut.ee/graphweb/welcome.cgi?t=examples) are some networks.